# initialize audiounit with kAudioFormatiLBC

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-audio, audiounit

i'm trying to initialize an AudioUnit to record audio using ilbc. Unfortunatly i need to use ilbc as codec and i cannot choose a different one.
after reading the documentation and forums I found that the correct stream descriptor for using ilbc should be something like:

```
streamDesc.mSampleRate = 8000.0;  
streamDesc.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatiLBC;  
streamDesc.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
```

then I use:

```
AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo,
                           0, NULL, &size, &streamDesc);
```

to fill the empty field in the structure, but i always get an error about the format.

anyone has some idea on the right parameters for the streamDesc?

thanks

Comment: This question cal help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021373/iphone-extended-audio-file-services-mp3-pcm-mp3

Comment: not really, my code works with linearpcm, i just dont know how to set the recorder to use ilbc

Answer (score 2):

You can't process a compressed stream format such as kAudioFormatiLBC though Audio Units or Graphs, this is not supported.

Comment: ok, but what is the best way to handle compressed audio formats on iOS then?