# Core audio codec error, not using `kAudioFormatLinearPCM`

Tags: ios, core-audio, codec

I have encountered an error.

I just want `kAudioFormatXXX` not `PCM`, but there are errors.

```
Error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215 "The operation 
couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)"
Error Code responded 1718449215 in file 
/Users/breaklee/Documents/project/ginav/ginav-
                            mobile/ginav-mobile/AudioProcessor.m on line 281
```

281 line is the end of code.

how can i initialize this code properly?

I want to use `iLBC` or other codecs not `PCM`.

AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;

```
audioFormat.mSampleRate         = SAMPLE_RATE;
audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatAC3;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | 
                                      kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;

audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 8;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 1;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 1;


// set the format on the output stream
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit,
      kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
  kInputBus,
  &audioFormat,
  sizeof(audioFormat));

[self hasError:status file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__];


// set the format on the input stream
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit,                     
    kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
    kAudioUnitScope_Input,
kOutputBus,
&audioFormat,
 sizeof(audioFormat));
[self hasError:status file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__];


/**
 We need to define a callback structure which holds
 a pointer to the recordingCallback and a reference to
 the audio processor object
 */
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;


// set recording callback
callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback; // recordingCallback pointer
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)(self);

// set input callback to recording callback on the input bus
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit,
            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
            kAudioUnitScope_Global,
    kInputBus,
    &callbackStruct,
    sizeof(callbackStruct));

[self hasError:status file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__];

/*
 We do the same on the output stream to hear what is coming
 from the input stream
 */
callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)(self);

// set playbackCallback as callback on our renderer for the output bus
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit,                                     
             kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
     kOutputBus,
     &callbackStruct,
     sizeof(callbackStruct));
[self hasError:status file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__];

// reset flag to 0
flag = 0;

/*
 we need to tell the audio unit to allocate the render buffer,
 that we can directly write into it.
 */
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit,
             kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
     kAudioUnitScope_Output,
     kInputBus,
     &flag,
     sizeof(flag));

     //    kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError

// Initialize the Audio Unit and cross fingers =)
status = AudioUnitInitialize(_audioUnit);

NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain
                                     code:status
                                 userInfo:nil];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);

[self hasError:status file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__];

NSLog(@"Started");
```

Comment: If you are targeting iOS, AC3 is not supported on device.

Comment: ah, but i changed to iLBC. there are same errors.
how can i use iLBC codec with my app? @cahn

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4259355/2570853. If your codec is not supported by iOS, you should use third party libraries for that.

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7127280/2570853.

Comment: @cahn thanks. that's not supported encoded stream.